# Pure javascript pull to refresh

Tags: javascript, html, pull-to-refresh

I've been looking for this for a few years now. I've tried libraries such as iscroll but I need something that doesn't affect the scrolling. Just a pure vanilla javascript pull-to-refresh without any dependancies such as iscroll or jquery.

Is this possible? It has to be smooth of course, I built one myself that didn't turn out all too great. I think it would go something like have a div that scrolls within a div that scrolls. Once you reach the top of the inner div you start scrolling the outer div and add your pull to refresh animation. Not quite sure though, thanks.

EDIT:

Alright here's what I got so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/y65wrw25/2/

```
    var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
    inner = document.getElementById('inner'),
    pull  = document.getElementById('pull');

// Start the outer scroller at the bottom
//
outer.scrollTop = pull.offsetHeight;

// On outer scroll
//
setTimeout(function(){
    outer.addEventListener('scroll', function(ev)
    {
        if (outer.scrollTop <= 100)
        {
            pull.innerText = 'Now release';
        }
        console.log(outer.scrollTop);
    }, false);
}, 200);
```

What would be the best method to add resistance to the scrolling of the outer div. In most pull and refreshes there's some resistance that increases the further down you pull. As you get to some distance, 200px for example, the scrolling speed on the outer div should slow to 0.

Comment: "Is this possible?" Yes, of course. Those other libraries are written in JavaScript, so everything jQuery can do, you can do yourself. And looking for *years*? Really?!

Comment: Anything possible with a javascript library is also possible without a javascript library.

Comment: Just go look at the underlying code of those libraries. I mean, I have a car with wheels. I'm not looking to create a way to make it roll around with some sort of rubber substance, I'd rather just use a tire someone made. But you can get to the bottom of it if you want. All those libs are open.

Comment: @GolezTrol yea every time I start a new project I search around for a plugin or tutorial but it seems no one has made one yet that doesn't rely on a library.

Comment: @AmritKahlon I wrote one for a Phonegap app of mine. I used CSS3 transitions so that it was nice and smooth. I could attempt to post an example if you were interested.

Comment: @Charlie That would be awesome! I'm using it with phonegap myself

Comment: @AmritKahlon give me a little to create a solid example.

Comment: @AmritKahlon So... it's been a tad longer than "a little"... are you still interested?

Comment: hey @Charlie yea for sure! I'm sure others would be interested as well

Answer (score 1):

folowing controller handles the reload of the page when you are on the top of the selected container. you can pass the controller the selector of the container you want to look for. In my case the container selector is #post. hopefully this will might help you. greetings from Germany:

```
 function reloadController(selector) {
    var self=this;
    var selected=document.querySelector(selector);
    var startScroll=null;
    var startPositionY=null;
    var endPositionY=null;
    self.fn= {
        start: function() {
            // add reload container
            var reloadContainer=document.createElement("div");
            reloadContainer.id="d21-reload-page-icon";
            reloadContainer.innerHTML="RELOAD";
            document.body.appendChild(reloadContainer);
            // start swipe listening
            selected.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
                startScroll=selected.scrollTop;
                startPositionY=e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
            }
            , false) selected.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
                var distance=self.fn.d21_calc_reload(e).distance;
                if(distance > 0) {
                    self.fn.d21_set_reloader(distance, true);
                }
                else {
                    self.fn.d21_set_reloader(0, false);
                }
            }
            , false) selected.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
                var touchInfo=self.fn.d21_calc_reload(e);
                self.fn.d21_set_reloader(0, false);
                if(touchInfo.isReload) location.reload();
            }
            , false)
        }
        ,
        d21_calc_reload: function(e) {
            var result= {
                isReload: false, distance: 0
            }
            ;
            endPositionY=e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
            var distance=endPositionY - startPositionY;
            if(distance > 0) {
                result.isReload=(startScroll - distance) < -200;
                result.distance=(startScroll - distance) * -1;
            }
            return result;
        }
        ,
        d21_set_reloader: function(position, show) {
            var reloadContainer=document.querySelector("#d21-reload-page-icon");
            reloadContainer.style.display=show ? "block": "none";
            reloadContainer.style.top=position + "px";
        }
    }
}

var rC=new reloadController("#post");
rC.fn.start();
```